# Docking laptop without sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, laptop, dock

Is there a setting or a procedure that allows me to dock a laptop and close it's lid (or close and dock) without it going to sleep?  No matter what I do, the laptop wants to go to sleep when the lid is closed.   I know I can turn this off in the power settings but I don't want to permanently disable going to sleep on close (when I am not docking).

Windows 7 and 10

Comment: Which OS. 12345

Comment: windows 7 and 10

Answer (score 0):

There are two power settings - one for plugged in and one for on battery power. You can just change the one for "plugged in" which should trigger with the dock. If you want it to behave differently when connected to the dock compared to plugged in with a power cord I don't think there's a built-in option.